# install4j: how to change the window title of the screens?

Tags: install4j

In Welcome screen the window title consists of *'Setup', dash*, product's *full name* and the *version*, see the screenshot. How can I change this text?

I want to get rid of the version information there in the title.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the General Settings->Languages step, set up a custom localization file, then open the built-in editor and click on the "Override messages" tool bar button. Search for the message you want to change and click on OK. Then you can change the text in the editor.

In your case, this is the key "SetupWindowTitle" and you can change it as shown in the screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: i have "SetupWindowTitle=Setup - ${compiler:sys.shortName} ${compiler:ssy.ReleaseVersion}" in my custom localization file and it doesnt work.
We are using Install4j 8.0.4

Comment: It works for me. Please send a test project to support@ej-technologies.com and we'll have a look at it.

Comment: ah i found the problem i thought i started the setup in english but i didnt and the custom localization file is defined for english